# matplotlib plot statement is not ploting

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hopefully there is an easy answer for this but I can't pinpoint why my code is not plotting. I copied and pasted the plot statement directly from an example code provided to me for solving IVP's such as mine then changed the variables to match what I have in my code. The example code plots without hesitation. Mine will not plot at all. I don't know what else to do. I am new to stackoverflow so I hope I add my code in a readable format.

```py
from a8odes import euler, rk4
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Spring Mass Damper function
def smd(t, y):
    
    # initializing variables
    k = 5.0
    m = 1.0
    c = 2.0
    
    # initializing ODE
    dydt = np.zeroes(2, dtype=float)
    dydt[0] = y[1]
    dydt[1] = -(k/m)*y[0] - (c/m)*y[1]
    return dydt
    
    #time interval
    t0 = 0.0
    tf = 6.0
    
    # step size
    h = 0.1
    
    # initial position
    y0 = np.array([1.0, 0.0], dtype=float)
    
    # simulate the system
    te, ye = euler(smd, y0, t0, tf, h)
    tr, yr = rk4(smd, y0, t0, tf, h)
    
    # getting values of analytical function
    ta = np.linspace(0, 6, len(te))
    ya = np.zeroes(len(te), dtype=float)
    for i in range(len(te)):
        ya[i] = np.exp(-ta[i])*(.5*np.sin(2*ta[i]) + np.cos(2*ta[i]))
    
    # plotting
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    axs[0].plot(te, ye[:, 0], 'b-o', label='Euler')
    axs[0].plot(tr, yr[:, 0], 'r-o', label='Heun')
    axs[0].set_title('position')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('t [s]')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('x [m]')
    axs[0].legend()
    axs[0].grid(True)
    axs[1].plot(te, ye[:, 1], 'b-o', label='Euler')
    axs[1].plot(tr, yr[:, 1], 'r-o', label='Heun')
    axs[1].set_title('velocity')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('t [s]')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('vel [m/s]')
    axs[1].legend()
    axs[1].grid(True)
    fig.suptitle('ODE Solver Results for Spring-Mass-Damper System')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your .plot() is inside the smd() function but I dont see you calling the function.

Comment: smd is called in line 28 and 39 under the # simulate the system comment. But I believe you led me to my error. All of my additional code was indented so that it was  under the smd function. I am unindenting to see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is bad. If you use [ast.parse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to parse your file. You can see that codes under your `return` statement is just being ignored.

```py
def smd(t, y):
    
    # initializing variables
    k = 5.0
    m = 1.0
    c = 2.0
    
    # initializing ODE
    dydt = np.zeroes(2, dtype=float)
    dydt[0] = y[1]
    dydt[1] = -(k/m)*y[0] - (c/m)*y[1]
    return dydt
|
V
    #time interval
    t0 = 0.0
    tf = 6.0
    ...
^
|
You shouldn't have indentation here
```

Comment: Thats exactly what the problem was. Thank you for your help! I am not familiar with ast.parse() but i am going to look it up. It sounds like a useful tool.

Comment: @jwal08 **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.